# Query has_many through association Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I have a has_many though association like this:

```
User.rb
has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy

has_many :groups, :through => :memberships

Group.rb
has_many :users, :through => :memberships
has_many :microposts


Membership.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :group
```

First I need to know the query to get all the groups of a user, after that I need a way to show all the microposts of those groups. Is it possible to get one query with that information?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a user's groups:

```
some_user = User.find(some_id)
some_user.groups
```

To get the microposts, you could do:

```
some_user.groups.each do |group|
  puts group
  puts group.microposts
end
```

However, this would cause a separate query to be generated to collect the microposts of each group.  This can be fixed by eager-loading the microposts using [`includes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations):

```
some_user.groups.includes(:microposts).each do |group|
  puts group
  puts group.microposts
end
```

Now only 2 queries will be generated - one to fetch the groups, and one to fetch *all* microposts associated with these groups.  Behind the scenes, ActiveRecord will match the microposts to the correct group, and return them accordingly when calling `.microposts` on a group.

To get all microposts as a hash, you can use `each_with_object` to collect them:

```
@group_microposts = some_user.groups.includes(:microposts).
                              each_with_object({}){|group, h| h[group] = group.microposts}
```

This will return a hash in the form `{ group => microposts }`.

To get them as an array, you *could* just do:

```
@microposts = some_user.groups.includes(:microposts).map(&:microposts).flatten
```

However, there is an even more efficient way to do this if you don't need the group information at all:

```
@microposts = Micropost.joins(:group => :users).where(:users => {id: some_user.id})
```

This second method is faster because of 2 reasons - it requires only a single query (no eager loading needed) and the db lookup is more efficient since it can use available indices to perform the necessary joins rather than filter against a literal integer list (which can get slow as the list gets larger).

Comment: Thanks! how can I save all the microposts of all the groups that belongs to a user in a instance variable? So in my view I can use @microposts or something like that...

Comment: Do you need them grouped by `group` or just as a big array of microposts?

Comment: Updated for both options ;)

Comment: Wow! how can I order it? like a condition, created at, or something like that, by the way I use the last option..

Comment: Use `.order(:created_at)` at the end.  If you need more complex logic, you can use any string acceptable in a SQL ORDER BY clause: `.order("groups.created_at, microposts.created_at, microposts.id DESC")`

Comment: Sorry for asking to much :p, I'm using the active record reputation system gem...http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system.... I'm trying to order those micropost by reputation, what do you think about it? I'm trying this:     @microposts = Micropost.joins(:group => :users).where(:users => {id: current_user.id}).order('votes desc')
But it sends the error SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: votes: SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts"

Comment: SQLite won't permit you to sort by a column that isn't being returned.  You can overcome this by adding it to the selected list of return values: `.select("microposts.*, votes")`

Comment: Where do I need to add that option? I've tried adding at the end but it sends an error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30294/discussion-between-julio-ahuactzin-and-pinnym)

Comment: @PinnyM Would u help me with something similar? I have user group and groupmembership which is the through relationship holder. groupmembership has a role attribute. I would like to retrieve users of a group with a specific role and i cant. i want something like group.users.where(:role => "Admin")

Comment: @AymanSalah please feel free to ask a question using the 'Ask Question' button.  If you feel it is relevant to this question, you can provide a link back to here.